# Что такое jsp/jsf?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsp, jsf

Недавно начал изучать веб на java. Из уроков понял что вроде как благодаря этим технологиям можно динамически менять внешний интерфейс страницы у клиента. Тем не менее хотелось бы получить более точный, подробный и понятный ответ.

Но это только половина вопроса. Сильно озадачило вот это видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuTkG_BtwL0. Судя по словам автора можно вообще обойтись без jsp/jsf отдав реализацию их функционала frontend'у. Позднее видел много тем по поводу смерти этих технологий. Почему возникают подобные темы?И что из себя представляет реализованный на frontend'е jsp/jsf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSP - это технология, позволяющая программисту создавать web-приложения наиболее простым способом, из доступных на платформе Java. Вы просто создаёте текстовый файл, содержащий html-разметку вперемешку с java-кодом

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello JSP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Текущее время: <%= new java.util.Date() %>
        Имя вашего хоста: <%= request.getRemoteHost() %>
    </body>
</html>
```

забрасываете её на сервер и открываете в браузере. Код внутри тега `<% %>` называется скриптлетом. Вместо написания кода в странице можно определять собственные теги. Для часто употребимых функций существует библиотека уже готовых тегов - JSTL.

JSP - это старая технология из конца 90-х, когда web-разработка только зарождалась. В то время идея смешивать код и представление не казалась ужасной, стремительно набирал обороты PHP, эксплуатирующий именно этот принцип. Но быстро стало понятно, что это ошибка. Поэтому на сегодняшний день JSP используется как средство написания шаблонов представления для web-приложений.

JSF - более сложная технология, служащая той же цели - разработке web-приложений. Она эксплуатирует компонентно-ориентированный подход - страница состоит из компонентов, каждый из которых подобен маленькой специально устроенной программке, совместно обрабатывающих запрос от клиента и формирующих ответ. Если JSP напоминает PHP, то JSF схож с ASP.NET.

---

> Судя по словам автора можно вообще обойтись без jsp/jsf отдав
>   реализацию их функционала frontend'у

Сейчас набирает популярность практика переноса слоя представления с бэкенда на фронтенд. То есть вместо того, чтобы из набора данных формировать html-страничку и отдавать её клиенту, сервер отдаёт клиенту данные в формате JSON (или другом), а javascript-код в браузере клиента из этих данных формирует элементы страницы. В такой схеме ни JSP, ни JSF не нужны, достаточно сервлета.

> Позднее видел много тем по поводу смерти этих технологий.

Люди склонны придумывать байки о конце света. Но слухи о смерти этих технологий сильно преувеличенны. JSP и JSF активно эксплуатируются и развиваются. В 2016-м году в составе Java EE 8 была выпущена обновлённая версия JSF.

> Почему возникают подобные темы?

Как я уже написал, JSP сейчас применяют только как шаблонизатор. И не самый популярный притом. У него есть сильные конкуренты, например Thymeleaf. А у JSF часть рынка откусил Spring MVC. Хотя сравнивать эти технологии не совсем корректно из-за разных подходов.

> И что из себя представляет реализованный на frontend'е jsp/jsf?

Почитайте про AJAX и RESTful web-сервисы. Полезно будет взглянуть на JAX-RS.

Answer (score 1):

HTML язык описывает статический контент который интерпретируется веб браузером на стороне клиента в привычный нам веб сайт. Соответственно когда Вы хотитите изменить наполнение страница то Вы, к примеру, отправляетесь на сервер и проводите мануальные изменения в соответствующем файле .html.

Автоматизацией это процесса занимаются технологии jsp:

Вы можете описать динамически модифицируемые блоки в шаблоне вашей страницы синтаксисом jsp и, к примеру,  логику в классах сервлетов.И наполнять HTML страницу исходя из обстоятельства.
К примеру изменяемую страницу приветствия пользователя)

Как вы понимаете это схоже с задачами которые решают такие языки и фреймворки как js ts angular etc.

Принципиальная разница в том что заполнение происходит на стороне сервера и происходит отправка всего контента или изменения были запрошенные с фронтэнд части и имплементированны на месте.

И как по мне не стоит рассматривать jsp/jsf как устаревшие технологии это всего лишь инструмент который который будет удобен в определенных обстоятельствах.

Я доверил бы к примеру приметив ныне выводы результатов работы какого-нибудь веб сервиса jsp чем на ровном месте добавлял в проект новый язык)